# How can I auto-remove unused imports using autoflake for my Python/Django4 project?

Tags: python-3.x, import, django-4.0, autoflake

I would like to auto-remove unused variables and imports in my Django 4/Python 3.9 project.  I have installed autoflake (3.1.0).  In my service file, I have a line like

```
from ..settings import PYTHON_ENV
```

which VSCode tells me

```
"PYTHON_ENV" is not accessedPylance
```

So I ran the autoflake command

```
autoflake --in-place --remove-unused-variables cbapp/services/my_service.py
```

but the unused imports remains.  What else do I need to do to have the unused imports removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says in the README that by default it only removes unused imports from the standard library. In order to remove *all* imports you need to give the `--remove-all-unused-imports` flag.

https://github.com/PyCQA/autoflake#advanced-usage

```
autoflake --in-place --remove-unused-variables --remove-all-unused-imports cbapp/services/my_service.py
```